# If the average age decreased by 6 months, calculate the average age of new students

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average, word-problem

> The average age of 12 students in exam hall is decreased by 6 months, when two of them aged 13 years and 15 years are replaced by two new students. The average age of new students is ?

I am not able to solve this problem and I am facing little ambiguity for solving, how the age will be decreased by six months? Any help appreciated please

Comment: The key here is that there are twelve students initially, and when these are joined by two new students, then there are fourteen in all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Age of each student is reduced by 6 month. So total age reduced is 72 months or 6 years.

It means 2 new students has age 6 years less.

Total age of replaced student = 28 years.

Total age of new students = 28 - 6 = 22 years.

Average age of 2 new students is 11 years.

Comment: @Kanwalijit singh, i want to talk to you , can you please come here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/calculus-and-analysis

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_{10}$ be the ages of the 10 students that did not move. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the ages of the two new students.
The original average is $$\frac{1}{12}(x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
and the new average is $$\frac{1}{12}(x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2).$$
Since the difference in the averages is $0.5$ years,
$$\frac{1}{12}(x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)
- \frac{1}{12}(x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2) = 0.5.$$
Can you rearrange to compute $\frac{1}{2}(y_1 + y_2)$?

Comment: how it will equal to 0.5, please explain@angryavian

Comment: @Learninguser 6 months is half a year

Comment: please solve till final step@angryavian , answer is 11

Comment: @Learninguser Where are you stuck?

Comment: first of all, if it is replaced by two new students,how the average will decrease in six months, it will decrease in that month only na, in question i am not able to understand @angryavian

Comment: @Learninguser The average age of the students is some number, like 14.3 years. After replacing two students, the problem states that this number decreases by 6 months (which is 0.5 years); in my example, the average would decrease to 13.8 years. It is not saying that it takes 6 months for the average to decrease.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58238/discussion-between-learning-user-and-angryavian).

Answer (score 3):

Decreasing the average age of the 12 students by 6 months will decrease the total age by $12 \times 6 = 72 \text{ months} = 6 \text{ years}$. Therefore, we choose $A_\text{new} = 11$, which is the solution to

$$\left(13 - A_\text{new}\right) + \left(15-A_\text{new}\right) = 6$$

Comment: I am not able to get it

Comment: Do you understand the part about decreasing the total age by 6 years?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_{10}$ be the ages of the 10 students that did not move. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the ages of the two new students.

The original sum of the age students is:

$$old = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
$$new = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2)$$

Multiply it by 12 to get the sum of months:

$$old = 12 (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
$$new = 12 (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2)$$

Compute the average in months:

$$old = \frac{1}{12} 12 (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
$$new = \frac{1}{12} 12 (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2)$$

As you can see, we can simplify the formulas to this:

$$old = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
$$new = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2)$$

We can reduce the formulas further since $$x_1+\cdots+x_{10}$$ are present in both and result and do not affect the result actually so just remove it.

$$old = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + 13 + 15)$$
$$new = (x_1+\cdots+x_{10} + y_1 + y_2)$$

Now we have two simple formulas:

$$old = (13 + 15)$$
$$new = (y_1 + y_2)$$

Now let solve the problem. What we know is the the new average is 6 months less than the old average.

$$new = old - 6$$

Technically we have everything we need to solve this:

$$new = (13 + 15) - 6$$
$$new = 28 - 6$$
$$new = 22$$
$$(y_1 + y_2) = 22$$

As we know that 22 is the sum for person y1 and y2, then the average will be:

$$\frac{1}{2} (y_1 + y_2) = \frac{1}{2} 22$$
$$\frac{1}{2} (y_1 + y_2) = 11$$

Answer (score 1):

y is the total age of the group.

x is the "average age".

We know the age of 2 students (13 + 15), the rest are not known.

13 + 15 + 10x = y

But if all students have the same age, they each need an additional half a year to compensate for the reduction of the average age of the group.

12 * (x + 0.5) = y

So...

13 + 15 + 10x = 12x + 6

22 = 2x

11 = x

Checking the numbers:

Old situation:

13 + 15 + 10 * 11 = 138

Old average age:

138 / 12 = 11.5

New average age is 11, and the counts are:

12 * 11 = 132

Compensating by adding half a year to each student:

12 * ( 11 + 0.5 ) = 12 * 11.5 = 138